# jquery accordion open certain panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have the following accordion jquery

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Content1</h3>
    <div>Content1</div>

    <h3>Content2</h3>
    <div>Content2</div>

    <h3>Content3</h3>
    <div>Content3</div>
</div>
```

and I want to open a certain panel programmatically by pressing on a button, so I did the following

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ active: 3 });
```

it works great but when I click the button again it collapse.. I want the panel to stay active each time I click the button, how to achieve this

here is Demo code

[Check out](https://jsfiddle.net/qz9gr2Lh/)

Comment: not getting your problem

Comment: what I want is to open a certain accordion panel when a user presses a button, but what I found was a toggle event( i mean when the panel is closed, the button opens it, and vice versa) that is not what I want, I was looking for a code to open a penel without "toggle"

Answer (score 0):

I have found this and it solve my problem

```
if(! $('.ui-accordion-header').hasClass("ui-state-active")){
    $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 3 });
}
```

This way I open the selected panel only if it is not opened.